# Login to a remote machine & accessing network resources

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

I want to access a file on remote machine(win2k3, 10.10.20.30), but i couldn't understand how to login to that machine in my program. is there any simple win api that takes network path, credentials and returns the handle?
i just want to access \10.10.20.30\c$\test.txt, 
WNetAddConnection2, WNetAddConnection3 are little confusing. Any suggestion will be helpful.

sorry for not being very clear. I want to access a computer on same network(LAN). 
I wanted to access a file that is not shared on other computer.

Comment: sorry for not being very clear. I want to access a computer on same network(LAN). Please ignore all corner cases like vpn, computer across networks etc. And the file i want access is not shared. i want to give credentials and then access.

Comment: Your `C$` syntax is hinting at a specific solution. That's an administrative share, i.e. you can't use it as a non-Administrator. ( Posted as a comment since it explains why it's not simple)

Comment: i've admin credentials. But I don't know how to use them in program, so that i will get access

Comment: Admin credentials that are valid across the network I assume?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you have administrator rights, the solution is fairly simple. The `C$` administrative share is available. You can call `WNetAddConnection2` to create a local driveletter pointing to it. `NETRESOURCE.dwType = RESOURCETYPE_DISK` of course, `.lpLocalName = NULL` as you don't need it, `.lpRemoteName = _T("\\\\10.10.20.30\\c$")` (note the escaping of \ in C strings, it really starts with 4 of them). `.lpProvider = NULL` - let Windows figure the provider out.

Leave the username/password empty, and Windows will use your current user credentials. If those are indeed (network) administrator credentials, they're sufficient.

`dwFlags` should include `CONNECT_TEMPORARY`, as you're only interested in one file.

However, I think that (given sufficient credentials) it's easier to just call `CreateFile("\\\\10.10.20.30\\c$\\test.txt")` and let Windows deal with the details.

Comment: Thanks alot Msalters, I just confused with usage of dwflags. Thanks for clearing my confusion.

Answer (score 0):

Normal c++ file access functions and libraries should work as is, just put the full network path to the file where you would put the file name, and you should be able to access. Good tutorials with sample code available at this link: http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/files/

If you are getting errors, check that the user you are logged in as has file permissions set on the shared folder, as well as sharing permissions.

Comment: sorry for not being very clear. I want to access a computer on same network(LAN). Please ignore all corner cases like vpn, computer across networks etc. And the file i want access is not shared. i want to give credentials and then access.

Comment: Answer revised - hopefully this is more helpful

Comment: Im not asking about file funtions like fopen or fclose etc. "check that the user you are logged in", i'm asking how to login to another machine from our c++ program to access some file on that machine. And the file is not shared at all.

Comment: I don't know all the ins and outs of Windows security, but there is no way I know of to remotely access a file that isn't shared or available on a web site. Not saying it is impossible, just that I don't know any way.

Answer (score -1):

Execute mstsc.exe from your code using [createprocess](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682425%28VS.85%29.aspx)... Rest of thing it will handle...

Comment: i donot want to do RDC to that machine. i just want to access one file .